# sort filter do not show null or blank value for filter

Tags: attributes, filter

i add custom sort filter to product say discount , when i sort this filter by desc order it show products with no discount, i want to add extra condition here to not show product with discount i sort by discount is done how can it be done please guide way .

i checked product listing file and found some function `getLoadedProductCollection()`

, can we do stuff there to fix it.

**config.xml**

```
  <core_collection_abstract_load_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <core_collection_abstract_load_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>sortit/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>sortit</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </core_collection_abstract_load_before_handler>
    </observers>
  </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
```

**Observer.php**

```
    class MY_Sortit_Model_Observer  extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
   {

            public function sortit(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                $collection = $observer->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
                $attribute = 'offers';
                $dir       = 'ASC'; //try both ASC and DESC
                $column    = "at_{$attribute}.value";
                $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("ISNULL({$column})"));
                $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("{$column} {$dir}"));

                return $collection;
            }

}
```

shows error :  Call to a member function getReadConnection() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to create an observer to add those filters. The reason for this is that any block of the type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` or any block that extends from it, has the product collection loaded in the `_beforeToHtml()` method just after the collection object is set on the toolbar.

There is an observer event named `catalog_block_product_list_collection` that you can hook into and it occurs just before the collection is loaded. However, with this particular block, I have found that it is best to filter this collection before it ever reaches the block by using the `core_collection_abstract_load_before` event and then performing some checks to make sure you are modifying the correct collection and only then modifying/filtering your collection.

When you don't do it this way, you may notice issues or inaccuracies with the toolbar or pagination for your category pages or search results pages.

If you want to sort a collection by a certain attribute and you want that attribute's `NULL` values pushed to the end, you can do it like this:

```
$attribute = 'discount';
$dir       = 'ASC'; //try both ASC and DESC
$column    = "at_{$attribute}.value";
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("ISNULL({$column})"));
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("{$column} {$dir}"));
```

Comment: where have i to add code you gave

Comment: To add an observer, you need to create a custom module first. Do you have one already?

Comment: no can you help with modul code for it

Comment: got error column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at_offers.value' in 'order clause',